# Access VBA Code

Tags: vba, ms-access

Could any expert tell me why I always get this error "Expected:End of Statement" when I run the following code in Access VBA :

```
FNSQL = DoCmd.RunSQL _
          "SELECT First_Name FROM tblPatient_Info WHERE Patient_ID = '" & 1967 & "';"
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: What is `FNSQL` and why are you assigning it to `DoCmd.RunSQL` method?

Comment: `DoCmd.RunSQL` executes SQL statements only for _action_ queries ( INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE, etc..). If you want to execute `Select` query, use [Recordset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197799(v=office.15).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Your code is wrong in a couple different ways.

You don't tell us what `FNSQL` is, so one can only imagine.

### Mistake #1

Mentioned by @simoco, `DoCmd.RunSQL` is used in the following scenarios:

Here's the API: `DoCmd.RunSQL SQLStatement UseTransaction`

**SQLStatement** : A string expression that's a valid SQL statement for an *action query or a data-definition query*. It uses an INSERT INTO, DELETE, SELECT...INTO, UPDATE, CREATE TABLE, ALTER TABLE, DROP TABLE, CREATE INDEX, or DROP INDEX statement.

Include an IN clause if you want to access another database.

### Mistake #2

**`FNSQL`**
I'm not sure what you are aiming to do with the results of the query, but this is for your general knowledge because if you didn't know the `RunSQL` syntax you may be unfamiliar with `Recordsets`.

You can assign your stored query's results to a `Recordset` and do with it as you please, much like a table.

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim SQL As String
Dim firstName As String

SQL = "SELECT First_Name FROM tblPatient_Info WHERE Patient_ID = 1967;"
' OR
SQL = "SELECT First_Name FROM tblPatient_Info WHERE Patient_ID = '" & 1967 & "';"
' You can write Debug.Print SQL to make sure you're getting the right SQL.

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(SQL)
' The disadvantage of this approach is that the query string must be compiled each time it runs
' OR
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(YourSaveQueryName)
'This would be the faster method of the 2.
```

You can then manipulate your data however you want, and loop through the entire recordset.

```
firstName = "Larry"

If rs.BOF And rs.EOF Then
' Do nothing, the recordset is empty
Else
   Do Until rs.EOF
      rs.Edit
      rs!FirstName = firstName 'This is how you access properties in the recordset
      rs.Update
      rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

etc.

Comment: Only one note to this great answer: on VBScript you can use & to add string to numbers, so in VBapplication is recommended that identify the type and this case is better patient_id = ' " & cstr(1967) & " ' "
No need to put the last ; on SQL sequence.

Comment: @Mastercafe Thanks for that. I enjoy when people clean up code snippets. Feel free to ever edit anything you see incorrect! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think you need parentheses around your SELECT statement when you pass it to `RunSQL`, because it's called as a function that returns "something" that gets assigned to `FNSQL`. So something like this:

```
FNSQL = DoCmd.RunSQL( _
          "SELECT First_Name FROM tblPatient_Info WHERE Patient_ID = '" & 1967 & "';")
```

In fact, looking at [the `RunSQL` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194626(v=office.15).aspx), `RunSQL` doesn't return anything so, even if you fix your original issue, you'll still find there's an error there.

Furthermore, again according to the documentation, you can only execute `SELECT ... INTO` statements with `RunSQL`. For simple `SELECT ... FROM` statements, simoco is right -- you need to use a `Recordset`.

Answer (score 0):

2 errors.

First, DoCmd.RunSQL won't do anything with just a select. Maybe you are missing your action (delete or something) or maybe you want to read it, so you should use CurrentDb.OpenRecordset . You'll need to post more code so we can better understand where you are going with this.

Second, if Patient_ID is an integer (and I'm guessing it is), you don't need the '. You don't need the ; either.

So the query should look like this:

```
varInt = 1967
"SELECT First_Name FROM tblPatient_Info WHERE Patient_ID = " & varInt
```

If you don't want to use a var for the int, just insert it directly into the string like so:

```
"SELECT First_Name FROM tblPatient_Info WHERE Patient_ID = 1967"
```

In case Patient_ID is a string, you  will indeed need ', but you are also missing " around the string, so it should look like this:

```
"SELECT First_Name FROM tblPatient_Info WHERE Patient_ID = '" & "1967" & "'"
```

Comment: You are aware that the question is almost 2 years old and was already answered comprehensively back then?

Comment: Loooool good call. For some reason it showed up in my search in the first page. I was under the impression the search was ordered by new entries, so I probably had a mistype on the search query (that is also mistyped here somewhere)

Comment: Also, no one had mentioned the integer and string difference in the query explicitly. IDs are usually integers, so it made sense to bring it up.

Answer (score 0):

Not a correct answer to this question but it's worth noting I just wanted to see if a row existed in the database. I assumed that would require me to write some sort of select or result query. However access has a separate function just to run count operations.

So this code I ended up with:

```
Dim count As Long
count = DCount("release_id", "list_releases", "list_id = 1 AND release_id = " & Me!release_id)
If count Then
  Me!owned.Enabled = False
  MsgBox "You own this release."
End If
```